# Distribution in Amazon Redhsift - BTree or Hash

Tags: amazon-redshift

What does Amazon Redshift use to distribute values in the cluster: Hash or BTree?

For example, if my distribution key is date in format "yyyy-MM-dd", are two subsequent days going to be stored on the same node (if Btree is used) or probably on different nodes (if hash is used, this will probably be the case)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart question. You know how most RDBMSs work.

There are no B-Trees.

A hashing function is applied to your distribution key, and the outcome of the hashing function determines what slice receives your data.

There are no indexes, in the traditional sense of the word. Redshift uses information in its "super block" to determine if it can avoid doing a full table scan for certain queries.

For large data sets there are 4 practices that will dramatically improve your performance:

1. [DISTRIBUTION KEY --- The most important design decision in an MPP
   system.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Distributing_data.html)
2. [COMPRESSION -- This can be done automatically as you load the database.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Compressing_data_on_disk.html)
3. [SORT KEY -- Getting a good sort key is extremely important for large
   tables.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html)
4. [ANALYZE and VACUUM --- This ensures that the SORT Key is optimized
   and the database has good statistics.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data-vacuum.html)

Notice what is missing from my list? Yes, I did not say indexes. Redshift does not have indexes.